# Failure to delete entire contact using ContentProviderOperation

Tags: android, contacts

I have been working with Android contacts. I am able to show them, update but
when I want to delete any, it is not deleted completely. In Contacts
application is shown as (Unknown) without any data. Here is my example:

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(Data.CONTENT_URI)
.withSelection(Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[]{selectedid})
.build());
getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

Should I do anything else to delete contact entirely?
It seems that these code delete info in table ContactsContract.Data but it does not delete element related in table ContactsContract.Contacts or ContactsContract.RawContacts.how can i do to delete an contact completely?

============================================================================

also, i tried deprecated method. It dose work, but i do not want to do so. Here is the sample code:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = m_cContent.getContentResolver();
contentResolver.delete(People.CONTENT_URI, People.NAME + "=?", new String[] { SelectedName });
```

and if i modify this code to

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = m_cContent.getContentResolver();
contentResolver.delete(ContactsContract.Contacts, ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + "=?", new String[] { Selectedid });
```

It has no effect.

Does it mean that one can only delete a contact by name instead of by its id?
What on earth can i do to delete contact?

Thanks,
Enchor

Comment: You have to run a sync process, so it updates with Google Contacts, than it will be removed permanently. Check for deleted flag.

Comment: “You have to run a sync process”
I do not know how to do so. Can you tell me how to run a sync process?
Please tell me what doc i can read or give me some sample code.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Enchor Did you solve your problem? I'm struggling with the same now.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to delete a **contact** by deleting its data rows from the `Data` table.
That wouldn't work.

A contact is made up of several raw-contacts, each raw-contact has its data saved in the `Data` table.
When deleting a contact, all raw-contacts get deleted as well, along with their data.

Do this:

```
long contactId = 12345;
Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(contactId));
int deleted = getContentResolver().delete(contactUri, null, null);
```

deleted will be 1 if the operation succeeded.